# How to track clicks or interactions within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, tracking

I have the following case:
I send traffic to a website I don't own. and I want to track conversions on that website (deposits they do on the accounts they create)

but this website does not have the ability to add either pixels or postback or anything else to send me back a parameter to track these conversions.

I have they url for my affiliate link and they update a daily list with the deposits and registrations they get from my link.

what I was thinking is to iframe this url at 100% and somehow track whenever an user clicks on some element in the iframe, to put a fire for my pixel so I can know from all the different sources of traffic I'm sending which ones at least are getting interaction (if tracking press on links on the iframe is out of the question)

I have the option to place a pixel on the page that I'll be using as the "prelander" in which I'll load the iframe.

this is the code for the iframe

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.website.com/dl/~offer?affiliate=2134567" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Tracking clicks inside the iframe, (if not possible to track clicks on specific places inside the iframe) will at least let me cut out the sources of traffic that are not having any interaction with the website inside the ifram

Comment: in simple words, you can't.

Comment: you can't even track an user clicking on the iframe? I haven't tried @Mark response yet, but that seems to be a way

Comment: you'd get some errors, looks like he mentioned it. any content you try to access or modify from another domain will behave like this. this is a security concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body iframe').contents().find('input').bind('click',function(e) {
    $.post(url,params,function(resp){
        //post back to you
    });
 });
```

Something like the above could work, however since this is not a site on your domain you are more than likely going to get the following XSS error:

*SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object*